# Magento 2 settings

Tags: magento2, multistore, multi-vendor

I'm selling different types of items. I sell on eBay using M2ePro and own website. For frontend I will use 1 menu for all the categories (electronics, clothes, beauty, etc) but I was thinking in the future to make a different design for example when a visitor clicks on a beauty category. In regards backend and admin, the m2epro people suggested me to create a new "store view" to be able to distinguish orders (in the sales view) coming from m2epro (ebay, amazon, etc) and orders coming directly from my site (in Magento 1 I weren't able to distinguish so I'm trying to make it better this time). Also, in the sales view I will need to distinguish orders coming from the different suppliers I have (right now in M1 I did it with a grid extension that shows sku, item title but this is not the most comfortable thing as I prefer to be able to filter them, let's say with an attribute like vendor # or probably a store view).

Comment: Kindly format the question so that users can easily understand what do you want. You can explain a bit more about your question.

Comment: Hello, I tried to explain the best as I can. Can you tell me which part is not understandable? Thanks!

Comment: Any help please?